# Prove that composition functions are surjective

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

There are 2 functions H,G $\colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ which defined like that:

$$H(x) = \begin{cases} 2x + 1 \end{cases}  $$

$$G(x)=\begin{cases}
x - 1  & if & x > 1\\
3 & if & x = 1\\
\end{cases}$$

we will define F $\colon \mathbb N^N \to \mathbb N^N$ like that:
$F(f) = G ∘ f ∘ H $

you need to prove that $F$ is Surjective.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: i showed that for any g(x) from Im(F) there is f(x) like that: f(x) = (g(x)+1)/2. which of course F(f) = g.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,  you need to prove that if there is a function

$h:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$

Then there is an $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ so that

$F(f) = G\circ f \circ H = h$.

So $F(f)(x) = G(f(H(x))) = h(x)$.

$G(f(2x+1)) = $

$\begin{cases}
f(2x+1) - 1  & if & f(2x+1) > 1\\
3 & if & f(2x+1) = 1\\
\end{cases}\\
=h(x)$

Let's map this out:

Case 1:

$n \to 2n+ 1 \to f(2n+1)\to f(2n+1) - 1 = h(n)$

We can have this happen by defining.  If $m = 2n + 1$ is odd.  Then $f(m) = h(\frac {m-1}2) + 1=h(n) + 1$

Note: as $h(n) + 1$ by definition is greater than $1$ so we don't need to worry about $f(2n+1) = 1$ and branching to $G(f(2n+1)) = 3 \ne h(n)$.

So..... there is no Case 2.

We haven't defined $f$ for even numbers or for the $m =1$.  We can do what ever we want in those case as $H(n)$ is never even or equal to $1$.

So define if $m = 2n$ then $f(m) = 3,567$.  Why not?

If $m = 1$ then $f(1) = 29$.  Why not?

And again if $m = 2n + 1$ is odd then $f(m) = h(\frac {m-1}2) + 1=h(n) + 1$

So:

$G(f(H(n)) = G(f(2n + 1))=g(h(n) + 1)= (h(n) + 1) -1 = h(n)$.

So There *does* exist an $f$ so that $F(f) = h$.  And so $F$ is surjective.  (But definitely *not* injective)